# Rewriting function as nested list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested

```
alist['a','b','Date','e','f']

def col_num_of(columnName,listObj):
    for ind,cell in enumerate(listObj):
        if cell==columnName:
            return ind

print(col_num_of('Date',alist))
```

How to write the above function as a one liner?

Failed Attempt:

```
def col_num_of(columnName,listObj):
    return ind if cell==columnName for ind,cell in enumerate(listObj)
```

Note: Please hold practicality and readability comments.  Thank you.

Comment: `['a','b','Date','e','f'].index('Date')` ?

Comment: Thank you that works great.  Any idea for educational purposes the correct way to write my failed attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, you are basically reimplementing `index`.

You current function returns the index of the first occurence of the searched item, or `None` if it is not found.

As a list comprehension (just for academica's sake) this could look like:

```
colNum = ([idx for idx, ele in enumerate(alist) if ele == 'Date'] + [None])[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> alist=['a','b','Date','e','f']
>>> alist.index('Date')
2
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(alist) if v=='Date']
[2]
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do the same thing as OP's function, but it surely points him into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

.index() will give you ValueError if the value you're looking for is not in the list.

```
>>> alist=['a','b','Date','e','f']
>>> alist.index('acc')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    alist.index('acc')
ValueError: 'acc' is not in list
```

Also if you have multiple occurrence of the string you're looking for, you will only get the first one.

```
>>> alist=['a','b','a']
>>> alist.index('a')
0
```

So either make sure you'll catch this error, or you can use the method by dawg:

```
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(alist) if v=='Date']
[2]
```

This will return empty list if no matches.

```
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(alist) if v=='accc']
[]
```